# Error while creating custom story on Facebook with Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am trying to use **Koala** gem to publish custom open graph stories to the **Facebook** timeline of the users of my Rails application. The application has already been approved to publish this custom story `batalharia:battle`, but when I try to share the user story there is the following error:

```
Koala::Facebook::ClientError (type: OAuthException, code: 100, error_subcode: 1611008, message: Invalid parameter, error_user_title: Object Missing a Required Value, error_user_msg: Object at URL 'https://batalharia.com/pt-BR/battles/27' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided. [HTTP 400]):
  app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:95:in `share_battle_on_facebook'
  app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:19:in `facebook'
```

The error message says that the type is `website` and that `og:title` was not provided, but my page is configured with `og:type` with `batalharia:battle` and `og:title` was provided.

The page I am trying to share is this one: https://batalharia.com/battles/27

And the Koala code is:

```
def share_battle_on_facebook(credentials, battle_id)
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(credentials.token)
  @graph.put_connections("me", "batalharia:create", battle: battle_url(battle_id))
end
```

Has someone faced this problem and knows how to fix it?

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

**Edit:**

If I **fetch new scrape information** for the page in the [facebook developers debug page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fbatalharia.com%2Fbattles%2F27), I get this error:

> Meta Tags In Body: Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the
>   head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower
>   in the parse tree. Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.

But the meta tags are in head and the HTML is ok. Despite the error pointed out, the tags are correctly identified and parsed by the debug page.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fbatalharia.com%2Fbattles%2F27

Comment: The debug tool from Facebook shows no errors, and yet I get the error mentioned above with Koala.